# Should I mark spring mvc DTO with Serializable?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, dto, serializable

We develop very usual spring MVC application
We have:
**Controller layer** (`@RestComtroller` + `@GetMapping` and `@PostMapping`)
**Service layer**(`@Service`)
**Repository layer** (`CrudRepository` from `spring-data-jpa`)

We use DTOs for communication between FE and BE.

Today my colleague asked me to mark all the DTOs as `implements Serializable` and add `serialVersionUID` field. I asked about reasons but he said that it is a "best practices". I am really confused about it. `Serializable` related to java serialization but we use JSON for BE and FE communication.

Could you clarify that question? So Should I mark spring mvc DTO with Serializable?

Comment: what exactly is FE and BE here? between controller and service? and do these DTOs actually get serialized at any point or are they just passed around within a running application?

Comment: @NathanHughes I assume that's FrontEnd (FE) and BackEnd (BE).

Comment: @Vinit: yes but it's ambiguous. also it's confusing how "we use DTOs for communication between FE and BE", then later it says "but we use JSON for BE and FE communication".  please clarify which is used where, in terms of the layers you've defined.

Comment: @Nathan Hughes, FE front end, BE - back end. We(actually spring do it) serialize DTO in json.

Comment: OK so you return a DTO from your controller, and a messageConverter builds json from that? right, in that case no point making the DTO serializable. only make it serializable if it needs to be stored or transferred across a network.

Answer (score 5):

No, you shouldn't.

Serialization implies that one side saves an object's state to a sequence of bytes while the other side rebuilds those bytes into a live object at some future time.

It means you should utilize Java Serialization API on the back-end side, pass the result over the network, and find a way how the received bytes can be helpful on the front-end side. The format of a serialized Java object is Java-specific and wasn't designed to be agnostic, so you will probably not find a reasonable (and short) way.

And you shouldn't (since you are communicating with the client via JSON).

Answer (score 1):

> The implementation of `java.io.Serializable` is simply required for
>   transfering data via **IIOP** or **JRMP** (**RMI**) between
>   JVM-instances. In case of a pure web application the domain objects
>   are sometimes stored in `HTTPSession` for **caching** purposes. A
>   http-session can be serialized or clustered. In both cases all the
>   content have to be **Serializable**.

In most cases, there is no reason do make DTO Serializable, but I would like to extend my answer by adding this idea that in a more pragmatic architectures, the **domain objects** could also be exposed directly to the presentation layer. So instead of copying the data from domain objects into DTOs, which violates **DRY Principal**, you could just pass the detached JPA-entities as value holders to the web application. In this case it is better to implement java.io.Serializable.

To be more specific regarding your question,you should consider the following two facts when you want to decide whether you need to implement `Serializable` or not: